# Android-Gradle - java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/widget/PositionMap.class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

i have a problem with a duplicate class in my dependencies.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
   defaultConfig {
       applicationId 'br.com.etm.checkseries'
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 23
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       multiDexEnabled true
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}

}
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
  compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'){
      exclude module : 'support-v4'
      exclude module : 'appcompat-v7'
  }

  compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.3.8@aar') {
      transitive = true
      exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
      exclude module: 'support-v4'
      exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
  }

  compile project(':unity-ads-1.5.6')

  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
  compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
  compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
  compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
  compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
  compile('com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0') {
      exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
  }
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
  compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.3.0'
  compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0') {
      exclude module: 'support-v4'
  }
  compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0') {
      exclude module: 'support-v4'
      exclude module: 'play-services-base'
  }
  compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0') {
     exclude module: 'support-v4'
  }
```

}

Always and when I run the application in an emulator API 16, this error occurs:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/widget/PositionMap.class

But when I run in an emulator API 20, the project run smoothly.